# Compiling multiple bash scripts into one binary file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, compilation, binary

I have a library that contains multiple bash scripts on a Linux. The main application, say `myApp.sh` will call different bash scripts to perform the tasks.

I have to compile all of these scripts into ONE binary file. With the SHC tool, I can only compile one file, and if I remove the other files, then the reference inside `myApp` is broken.

So how can I compile all of the bash scripts into one file and then run SHC on it?